# Puppeteer won't click on Facebook cookie notice, no matter what

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to make a script that will load up facebook, type in an email and password and automatically log in. However, when opening the url "https://facebook.com/login", after around 0.5s, a cookie notice appears. I am trying to make Puppeteer click on the 'Accept' button but it doesn't want to do it for some reason?

So because of this, the program never advances because it cannot click the button. Could somebody look at my code and let me know where I am going wrong?

index.js (relevant portion):

```
let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    if (Object.keys(cookies).length) {
        await page.setCookie(...cookies);
        await page.goto('https://www.facebook.com/');
    } else {



        await page.goto('https://www.facebook.com/login', {
            waitUntil: 'networkidle0'
        });

        await page.waitForNavigation('load')

        // await page.waitForSelector('#u_0_i_6I', {
        //     visible: true
            // })

            // I TRIED THE ABOVE COMMENTED OUT CODE, DIDN'T WORK

        await delay(3000)
        // SO I TRIED MANUALLY WAITING 3 SECONDS FOR THE NOTICE TO LOAD IN BEFORE I CLICK IT

        
        await page.click('#u_0_i_6I') //COOKIE NOTICE ACCEPT BUTTON ID
```

Comment: One thing I can recommend is to avoid relying on ids and html attributes that seem automatically generated as these can change quite frequently.

Answer (score 1):

this is part of my puppeteer code for solution facebook cookie notice and login:

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: ['--start-maximized']
  });

  const FB_COOKIE = 'button[data-cookiebanner]:first-child';
  const FB_USERNAME = '#email';
  const FB_PASSWORD = '#pass';
  const FB_LOGIN = 'button[name="login"]';

  const fb = await browser.newPage()

  await fb.goto('https://facebook.com');
  await fb.waitForTimeout(1000);
  await fb.waitForSelector(FB_COOKIE, { delay: 500 });
  await fb.click(FB_COOKIE);
  await fb.waitForSelector(FB_USERNAME, { delay: 500 });
  await fb.waitForTimeout(500);
  await fb.focus(FB_USERNAME);
  await fb.type(FB_USERNAME, "" + users[0].fb_login, { delay: 15 });
  await fb.waitForSelector(FB_PASSWORD, { delay: 500 });
  await fb.waitForTimeout(500);
  await fb.focus(FB_PASSWORD);
  await fb.type(FB_PASSWORD, "" + users[0].fb_pass, { delay: 15 });
  await fb.waitForTimeout(500);
  await fb.click(FB_LOGIN);
  await fb.waitForTimeout(5000);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Thank you for reminding.
Each time you open Facebook in a new Puppeteer window, the page element identifiers are changed. This is happening all over Facebook.
That's why I used my code to find the `Button` element by an attribute called `data-cookiebanner`, which doesn't change. There are two of these buttons, so I always choose the first `first-child` in FB_COOKIE element definition.

Answer (score -1):

**I'm not an expert. But, here is what I found useful for me.**

Sometimes *page.click()* doesn't work for me. Maybe this is the case for you. If that is the problem, You can use

```
page.evalute(//(a function to execute in chrome dev tool environment))
```

or, use

```
page.$eval(//(...a selector), //(...a callback function using that selector as argument))
```

You can read more about the function on the internet by searching the function name.

Then inside the browser context function, you can execute any chrome dev tool function you want. If you use *page.evaluate()*, you can

```
document.querySelector('<classname or anyother selector>').click()
```

or better

```
$('<selector>').click()
```

I hope this is helpful for you.